# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. Function can work alone fine but lead to error when use inside another function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
def netwon(f, J, p0, tol):
    for i in range(1,51):
        p = p0 - J(p0)/f(p0)
        if la.norm(p - p0) < tol:
            break
        p0 = p
    return p

def JJ(x):
    J = np.identity(4)
    u = sum(x)
    for i in range(0,4):
        for j in range(0,4):
            J[i][j] = J[i][j] + ((np.e**(np.cos(u))) * (np.sin(u)))
    return J
```

### Throws this error message when calling newton:

```
netwon(f, JJ, [2.5, 2, 1.4, 9], 1*10**-12)
-
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-b80f7ad38c88> in <module>()
----> 1 netwon(f, JJ, [2.5, 2, 1.4, 9], 1*10**-12)

<ipython-input-44-ae7c3122a6cf> in netwon(f, J, p0, tol)
      1 def netwon(f, J, p0, tol):
      2     for i in range(1,51):
----> 3         p = p0 - (J(p0)/f(p0))
      4         if la.norm(p - p0) < tol:
      5             break

<ipython-input-53-17a5f32512be> in JJ(x)
      4     for i in range(0,4):
      5         for j in range(0,4):
----> 6             J[i][j] = J[i][j] + ((np.e**(np.cos(u))) * (np.sin(u)))
      7     return J

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I am able to use JJ fine by itself:

```
JJ([2.5, 2, 1.4, 9])
array([[1.36222766, 0.36222766, 0.36222766, 0.36222766],
       [0.36222766, 1.36222766, 0.36222766, 0.36222766],
       [0.36222766, 0.36222766, 1.36222766, 0.36222766],
       [0.36222766, 0.36222766, 0.36222766, 1.36222766]])
```

Can someone spot my error here, I don't understand why JJ can work alone but lead to error when use inside another function.

Thanks

Comment: What value are you using for  `f`?

Comment: what is the function `f` and what is `la`? If i create a dummy f function, the code works.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh `la` is `numpy.linalg`

Comment: f is def f(x):
    return x - np.e**(np.cos(np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])*sum(x)))

Comment: thanks, it still doesn't seem to provide me with the right answer. f is [def f(x):
    return x - np.e**(np.cos(np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])*sum(x)))].  I coded all this in matlab and the output should be a (4,) array . @ParitoshSingh. Can you further help me on this?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Never mind, i find out where I am getting thing wrong. Thanks for your great input

Comment: No worries! @YUANFENGHU

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the shape of p0 between first and second iterations of your newton function. In the first go, it is a 1 dimensional array (4,) but it is being reassigned to a 2 dimensional array (4,4). JJ fails when it is fed a 2 dimensional array, because the sum function does not collapse 2d arrays into a single value, but a 1d array instead.
PS. I am using a dummy f function because the original f function is not provided, however i presume the f function will not cause a change in the shape of the resultant p0.

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return 1

def netwon(f, J, p0, tol):
    for i in range(1,51):
        p = p0 - J(p0)/f(p0)

#        if la.norm(p - p0) < tol:
        if i ==1: #at first iteration, p0 which used to be a (4,) array will be replaced with a (4,4)
            global inspect
            inspect = p
            break
        p0 = p
    return p

def JJ(x):
    J = np.identity(4)
    u = sum(x)
    for i in range(0,4):
        for j in range(0,4):
            J[i][j] = J[i][j] + ((np.e**(np.cos(u))) * (np.sin(u)))
    return J

a = [2.5, 2, 1.4, 9]
netwon(f, JJ, a, 1*10**-12)
#fine till here
print(inspect) #no longer a (4,) array. It is now a (4,4)
print(sum(inspect)) #no longer a single value, but a (4,) array
u = sum(inspect)
((np.e**(np.cos(u))) * (np.sin(u))) #no longer a single value.

# J[i][j] = J[i][j] + ((np.e**(np.cos(u))) * (np.sin(u))) #1 location is now attempting to be assigned with an array
JJ(inspect) #will result in error.
```